# How to find the assemblies used by a .NET Core project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

What's the most direct way of finding the assemblies referenced by a .NET Core 3.1 project? I created a test .NET Core 3.1 Windows Forms project and when iterating over the loaded assemblies on startup I can see that it only uses about a dozen assemblies (System.Runtime, System.Windows.Forms, etc.). From the 'Location' property of each Assembly object, I can see that the assemblies reside in:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
and
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App

However, from another program examining the project folder, I can't see these assemblies referenced in a readable file used by that project. With .NET Framework projects you could just find the assemblies in the project file, but now the project file has almost no information - just:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Is there an algorithm for finding these assemblies from the human-readable (non-binary) project files?
It's not enough to find the folders since there are hundreds of assemblies in C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared. I need to narrow down the ones actually used.

The purpose is to find these assemblies to reflect on them to assist in proper source code conversion. At some point in early .NET Core it seemed that the assemblies were copied to the project bin folder, which made things incredibly easy, but I don't see that happening now with .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Only public object can be seen by other projects.  You can use VS Solution Explorer and right click object in the Reference and look under properties to see the namespace. To access the references you need to use the full namespace of the objects.  If the dll are not in the bin folder then they must be in a different sub folder under bin if you are not getting compiler errors and you added the dll as references.

Comment: @jdweng: Not adding any dlls manually - they are automatically referenced by .net core project by default.

Comment: For instance, "System.Runtime" is not explicitly stated in any project file in the entire project folder, but it is one of the loaded assemblies and the path is in C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared, and I need to know how to find that information from the project information in the project folder.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#description `.deps.json` should contain everything you need to know.

Comment: @LexLi: I don't have control over the projects submitted for conversion, so I can't assume they've published.  Also, when I use the "publish" via Visual Studio, which I assume is just another way of doing this, it doesn't copy any assemblies to the project folder.

Comment: The are default references added and the will be shown in the Solution Explorer References.  You can also see them in the csproj file if you open with notepad.  All reference dlls are shown in project file.  The Net Library references are not copied to the bin folder, but all others are copied.

Comment: @jdweng: My test project file contents is listed in my post and no sign of the dozen .NET assemblies is in it. Create a new .net core 3.1 project and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas You can publish your app (not a single file) and examine `deps.json` file

Comment: The libraries are just packed into one file instead of multiple files.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/distribution-packaging

Comment: @jdweng: The link you provided does not show how to isolate just the assemblies actually loaded by the application.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: The deps.json file does not show the individual system assemblies loaded by the application.  For instance, my test application uses System.Drawing.Common - no mention of this assembly is in any of the files in the application folder or sub-folder.